# Al hacer reload del DataTables se intercambian las filas porque el json devuelto ya viene en otro orden

Tags: datatables, symfony, doctrine2, symfony5

Tengo un DataTables construido `serverside` que me he dado cuenta cuando tiene más de una página y le hago `datatables.ajax.reload(null, false)` me cambia el orden de las filas aleatoriamente dentro del mismo rango de filas (dentro de la misma página del datatables). Al hacer llamar a la función `actualizarDataTable(_dtAPI, false)` veo que el `JSON` que retorna el `Repository` ya viene con los registros intercambiados, y cada 3 llamadas se vuelve a reestablecer el orden. No tengo idea de por qué el comportamiento, en la configuración javascript las columnas están a `orderable=false`, y en la consulta a la BD siempre se hace un `order by` sobre la misma columna, es decir no utilizo el orden proveniente del lado del cliente.

Cliente side:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var _tablaDatosElement = $('#tablaDatos');
    var _dtAPI = $(_tablaDatosElement)
            .on('draw.dt', function () {
                $(_tablaDatosElement).find('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
            })
            .on('preXhr.dt', function (e, settings, data) {
                data.verTodos = $('#chkVerTodos').prop('checked') ? true : false;
                data.columns = [];
            })
            .on('xhr.dt', function (e, settings, json, xhr) {
                switch (xhr.status) {
                    case 0:
                        toastr.error("Conexión interrumpida!!!", '', {
                            timeOut: 2100,
                            preventDuplicates: false,
                            positionClass: 'toast-top-center',
                            progressBar: true,
                            showDuration: 800,
                            hideDuration: 400,
                            extendedTimeOut: 1000,
                            showEasing: "swing",
                            hideEasing: "linear",
                            showMethod: "fadeIn",
                            hideMethod: "fadeOut",
                        });
                        break;
                    case 401:
                        toastr.error("Su sesión ha expirado. No es posible realizar la operación.", '', {
                            timeOut: 2400,
                            preventDuplicates: false,
                            positionClass: 'toast-top-center',
                            onHidden: function () {
                                window.location = _HOMEPAGE;
                            }
                        });
                        break;
                    case 400:
                    case 403:
                    case 404:
                    case 406:
                    case 500:
                        toastr.error(xhr.responseText, '', {
                            timeOut: 2500,
                            preventDuplicates: false,
                            positionClass: 'toast-top-center',
                            progressBar: true,
                            showDuration: 800,
                            hideDuration: 400,
                            extendedTimeOut: 1000,
                            showEasing: "swing",
                            hideEasing: "linear",
                            showMethod: "fadeIn",
                            hideMethod: "fadeOut",
                        });
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            })
            .on('init.dt', function () {
                $('#contenedorTablaDatos').removeClass('hidden');
            })
            .DataTable({
                "columns": [
                    {"data": "numero", "className": "text-center", "searchable": false, "orderable": false},
                    {"data": "nombre", "className": "text-left", "searchable": false, "orderable": false},
                    {"data": "edad", "className": "text-center", "searchable": false, "orderable": false},
                    {"data": "fum", "className": "text-center", "searchable": false, "orderable": false},
                    {"data": "eg", "className": "text-center", "searchable": false, "orderable": false},
                    {"data": "fpp", "className": "text-center", "searchable": false, "orderable": false},
                    {"data": "ingresos_link", "className": "text-center", "searchable": false, "orderable": false},
                    {"data": "editar_link", "className": "text-center", "searchable": false, "orderable": false},
                    {"data": "nacimientos_link", "className": "text-center", "searchable": false, "orderable": false},
                    {"data": "finalizar_link", "className": "text-center", "searchable": false, "orderable": false},
                    {"data": "eliminar_link", "className": "text-center", "searchable": false, "orderable": false},
                ],
                "columnDefs": [
                    {"name": "numero", "targets": 0, "className": "text-center", "searchable": false, "orderable": false},
                    {
                        "name": "nombre",
                        "targets": 1,
                        "orderable": false,
                        "searchable": false,
                        "render": function (data, type, full) {
                            if (full['emb_fallecida'] === true) {
                                return '<a class="lnkCargarVista" data-src="' + data.src + '" data-toggle="tooltip" title data-original-title="Ver Hoja resumen">' + data.nombre + ' <b>(FALLECIDA)</b></a>';
                            } else {
                                return '<a class="lnkCargarVista" data-src="' + data.src + '" data-toggle="tooltip" title data-original-title="Ver Hoja resumen">' + data.nombre + '</a>';
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {"name": "edad", "targets": 2, "className": "text-center", "searchable": false, "orderable": false},
                    {"name": "fum", "targets": 3, "className": "text-center", "searchable": false, "orderable": false},
                    {
                        "name": "eg",
                        "targets": 4,
                        "searchable": false,
                        "orderable": false,
                        "render": function (data, type, full) {
                            if (full['emb_finalizado'] === false) {
                                if (data.enabled === true) {
                                    return '<a class="dtBtnActualizarEG lnkCursorPuntero" data-src="' + data.src + '" data-toggle="tooltip" title data-original-title="Actualiar E.G">' + data.eg + '</a>';
                                } else {
                                    return data.eg;
                                }
                            } else {
                                return data.eg;
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {"name": "fpp", "targets": 5, "searchable": false, "orderable": false},
                    {
                        "name": "ingresos_link",
                        "targets": 6,
                        "render": function (data, type, full) {
                            return '<a class="lnkCargarVista" data-src="' + data + '" data-toggle="tooltip" title data-original-title="Ver Historial de ingresos"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span></a>';
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "editar_link",
                        "targets": 7,
                        "render": function (data, type, full) {
                            if (data.enabled === true) {
                                return '<a class="dtBtnEditar btn btn-xs btn-primary btn-flat" data-src="' + data.src + '" data-toggle="tooltip" title data-original-title="Editar registro"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span>&nbsp;Editar</a>';
                            } else {
                                return '<a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary btn-flat disabled"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span>&nbsp;Editar</a>';
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "nacimientos_link",
                        "targets": 8,
                        "render": function (data, type, full) {
                            if (data.enabled === true) {
                                return '<a class="dtBtnNacimientos btn btn-xs btn-primary btn-flat" data-src="' + data.src + '" data-toggle="tooltip" title data-original-title="Registrar nacimientos"><span class="fa fa-plus-sign"></span>&nbsp;Nacimientos</a>';
                            } else {
                                return '<a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary btn-flat disabled"><span class="fa fa-plus-sign"></span>&nbsp;Nacimientos</a>';
                            }
                        }

                    },
                    {
                        "name": "finalizar_link",
                        "targets": 9,
                        "render": function (data, type, full) {
                            if (data.enabled === true) {
                                return '<a class="dtBtnFinalizarEmbarazo btn btn-xs btn-primary btn-flat" data-src="' + data.src + '" data-toggle="tooltip" title data-original-title="Finalizar embarazo"><span class="fa fa-power-off"></span>&nbsp;Finalizar</a>';
                            } else {
                                return '<a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary btn-flat disabled"><span class="fa fa-power-off"></span>&nbsp;Finalizar</a>';
                            }
                        }

                    },
                    {
                        "name": "eliminar_link",
                        "targets": 10,
                        "render": function (data, type, full) {
                            if (data.enabled === true) {
                                return '<a class="dtBtnEliminar btn btn btn-xs btn-danger btn-flat" data-src="' + data.src + '" data-toggle="tooltip" title data-original-title="Eliminar embarazada"><span class="fa fa-remove"></span>&nbsp;Eliminar</a>';
                            } else {
                                return '<a class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btn-flat disabled" data-toggle="tooltip" title data-original-title="Eliminar embarazada"><span class="fa fa-remove"></span>&nbsp;Eliminar</a>';
                            }
                        }

                    }

                ],
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax": {
                    "url": $(_tablaDatosElement).data('src'),
                    "type": "POST"
                },
                "searchDelay": 1000,
                "paging": true,
                "info": true,
                "searching": true,
                "lengthChange": false,
                "order": false,
                "autoWidth": true,
                "FixedHeader": true,
                "responsive": true,
                "language": {
                    "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros por p&aacute;gina",
                    "zeroRecords": "No se encontraron registros",
                    "info": "Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
                    "infoEmpty": "No se encontraron registros",
                    "emptyTable": "No hay registros disponibles",
                    "infoFiltered": "(filtrados de _MAX_ registros totales)",
                    "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
                    "processing": "Cargando...",
                    "search": "Buscar por Nombre o N&uacute;mero de Identidad:",
                    "paginate": {
                        "first": "Primera",
                        "last": "&Uacute;ltima",
                        "next": "Siguiente",
                        "previous": "Anterior"
                    }
                },
                "stateSave": true,
                "stateDuration": 60 * 60 * 24,
                "stateSaveCallback": function (settings, data) {
                    try {
                        data.verTodos = $('#chkVerTodos').prop('checked');
                        localStorage.setItem('DTembcmf' + _tablaDatosElement.data('cmf'), JSON.stringify(data));
                    } catch (e) {
                        console.log('on stateSaveCallback ' + e.message);
                    }
                },
                "stateLoadCallback": function (settings) {
                    try {
                        var estado = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('DTembcmf' + _tablaDatosElement.data('cmf')));
                        if (estado !== null) {
                            $('#chkVerTodos').prop('checked', estado.verTodos);
                        }
                        return estado;
                    } catch (e) {
                        console.log('on stateLoadCallback ' + e.message);
                    }
                },
                "createdRow": function (row, data, dataIndex) {
                    if (data['emb_aro'] === true) {
                        $(row).toggleClass('danger');
                    }
                }
            });

    $('#lnkActualizarDataTables').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        actualizarDataTable(_dtAPI, false); // simplemente _dtAPI.ajax.reload(null, false);
    });

    $('#lnkRegistrarEmbarazada').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        var elemento = $(this);
        agregarRegistro(elemento, _dtAPI, true);
    });

    $(_tablaDatosElement).find('tbody').on('click', 'a.dtBtnActualizarEG', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        var elemento = $(this);
        editarRegistro(elemento, _dtAPI);
    });

    $(_tablaDatosElement).find('tbody').on('click', 'a.dtBtnEditar', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        var elemento = $(this);
        editarRegistro(elemento, _dtAPI);
    });

    $(_tablaDatosElement).find('tbody').on('click', 'a.dtBtnEliminar', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        var elemento = $(this);
        eliminarRegistro(elemento, _dtAPI);
    });

    $(_tablaDatosElement).find('tbody').on('click', 'a.dtBtnFinalizarEmbarazo', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        var elemento = $(this);
        editarRegistro(elemento, _dtAPI);
    });

    $(_tablaDatosElement).find('tbody').on('click', 'a.dtBtnNacimientos', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        var elemento = $(this);
        editarRegistro(elemento, _dtAPI);
    });

    $('#chkVerTodos').iCheck({
        checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal-blue',
    }).on('ifChanged', function (e) {
        actualizarDataTable(_dtAPI, false); // simplemente _dtAPI.ajax.reload(null, false);
    });
});
```

Controller:

```
public function DTableEmbarazadasNodoCMFAction(Request $request, ManagerRegistry $manager, UuidEncoder $uuidEncoder, LoggerInterface $logger): Response
    {
        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            try {
                if (!$request->isMethod(Request::METHOD_POST)) {
                    throw new \Exception("Operación no soportada", 406);
                }

                $cmfId = $uuidEncoder->decode($request->get('estructuraId'));
                $draw = $request->request->getInt('draw');
                $start = $request->request->getInt('start');
                $length = $request->request->getInt('length', \intval($this->getParameter('resultados_por_pagina')));
                $filtro = $request->get('search');
                $verTodos = $request->request->getBoolean('verTodos', false);

                $em = $manager->getManager();

                $cmf = $em->getRepository(EstructuraOrganizativa::class)->findOneJoinTipoEstructuraOrganizativa($cmfId);
                if (\is_null($cmf) || ($cmf->getTipoEstructuraOrganizativa()->getId() !== 6)) {
                    throw new \Exception("No se encontró el CMF seleccionado!!!", 404);
                }

                $resultado = $em->getRepository(Embarazada::class)->embarazadasPorEstructuraDTable($cmf, $start, $length, $verTodos, $filtroNombre = $filtro['value']);
                $data = [];
                $numero = $start + 1;
                foreach ($resultado['results'] as $embarazada) {
                    $data[] = [
                        'emb_aro' => $embarazada->getEsDeAltoRiesgo(),
                        'emb_finalizado' => $embarazada->getEmbarazoFinalizado(),
                        'emb_fallecida' => $embarazada->getFallecida(),
                        'DT_RowId' => $uuidEncoder->encode($embarazada->getIdPublico()),
                        'numero' => $numero,
                        'nombre' => [
                            'nombre' => $embarazada->getNombre(),
                            'src' => $this->generateUrl('embarazada_hoja_resumen', ['id' => $uuidEncoder->encode($embarazada->getIdPublico())])
                        ],
                        'edad' => $embarazada->getEdad(),
                        'fum' => $embarazada->getFechaUltimaMenstruacion()->format('d/m/Y'),
                        'eg' => [
                            'eg' => $embarazada->getEmbarazoFinalizado() ? '<b>FINALIZADO</b>' : $embarazada->getEdadGestacional(),
                            'src' => $this->generateUrl('embarazada_actualizar_eg', ['id' => $uuidEncoder->encode($embarazada->getIdPublico())]),
                            'enabled' => (($this->isGranted(AppRoles::ROLE_ESP_MUN) || $this->isGranted(AppRoles::ROLE_ESP_AS) || $this->isGranted(AppRoles::ROLE_EST_MUN) || $this->isGranted(AppRoles::ROLE_EST_AS) || $this->isGranted(AppRoles::ROLE_J_GBT) || $this->isGranted(AppRoles::ROLE_EST_GBT) || $this->isGranted(AppRoles::ROLE_MEDICO)) && $embarazada->getEmbarazoFinalizado() === false) ? true : false
                        ],
                        'fpp' => $embarazada->getEmbarazoFinalizado() ? $embarazada->getFechaFinalizado()->format('d/m/Y') : $embarazada->getFpp()->format('d/m/Y'),
                        'ingresos_link' => $this->generateUrl('ingreso_historial_embarazada', ['embarazadaId' => $uuidEncoder->encode($embarazada->getIdPublico())]),
                        'editar_link' => [
                            'src' => $this->generateUrl('embarazadas_editar', ['id' => $uuidEncoder->encode($embarazada->getIdPublico())]),
                            'enabled' => (($this->isGranted(AppRoles::ROLE_ESP_MUN) || $this->isGranted(AppRoles::ROLE_ESP_AS) || $this->isGranted(AppRoles::ROLE_EST_MUN) || $this->isGranted(AppRoles::ROLE_EST_AS) || $this->isGranted(AppRoles::ROLE_J_GBT) || $this->isGranted(AppRoles::ROLE_EST_GBT) || $this->isGranted(AppRoles::ROLE_MEDICO)) && $embarazada->getEmbarazoFinalizado() === false) ? true : false
                        ],
                        'nacimientos_link' => [
                            'src' => $this->generateUrl('nacimiento_registrar', ['embarazadaId' => $uuidEncoder->encode($embarazada->getIdPublico()), 'unidadRegistraId' => $uuidEncoder->encode($embarazada->getCmf()->getIdPublico())]),
                            'enabled' => (($this->isGranted(AppRoles::ROLE_ESP_MUN) || $this->isGranted(AppRoles::ROLE_ESP_AS) || $this->isGranted(AppRoles::ROLE_EST_MUN) || $this->isGranted(AppRoles::ROLE_EST_AS) || $this->isGranted(AppRoles::ROLE_J_GBT) || $this->isGranted(AppRoles::ROLE_EST_GBT) || $this->isGranted(AppRoles::ROLE_MEDICO)) && $embarazada->getEmbarazoFinalizado() === false) ? true : false
                        ],
                        'finalizar_link' => [
                            'src' => $this->generateUrl('embarazada_finalizar_embarazo', ['id' => $uuidEncoder->encode($embarazada->getIdPublico())]),
                            'enabled' => (($this->isGranted(AppRoles::ROLE_ESP_MUN) || $this->isGranted(AppRoles::ROLE_ESP_AS) || $this->isGranted(AppRoles::ROLE_EST_MUN) || $this->isGranted(AppRoles::ROLE_EST_AS) || $this->isGranted(AppRoles::ROLE_J_GBT) || $this->isGranted(AppRoles::ROLE_EST_GBT) || $this->isGranted(AppRoles::ROLE_MEDICO)) && $embarazada->getEmbarazoFinalizado() === false) ? true : false
                        ],
                        'eliminar_link' => [
                            'src' => $this->generateUrl('embarazadas_eliminar', ['id' => $uuidEncoder->encode($embarazada->getIdPublico())]),
                            'enabled' => (($this->isGranted(AppRoles::ROLE_ESP_MUN) || $this->isGranted(AppRoles::ROLE_ESP_AS) || $this->isGranted(AppRoles::ROLE_EST_MUN) || $this->isGranted(AppRoles::ROLE_EST_AS) || $this->isGranted(AppRoles::ROLE_J_GBT) || $this->isGranted(AppRoles::ROLE_EST_GBT) || $this->isGranted(AppRoles::ROLE_MEDICO)) && $embarazada->getEmbarazoFinalizado() === false) ? true : false
                        ],
                    ];
                    $numero += 1;
                }
                $dataRespuesta = [
                    'draw' => (int) $draw,
                    'recordsTotal' => \intval($resultado['totalResults']),
                    'recordsFiltered' => \intval($resultado['countResults']),
                    'data' => $data
                ];

                return new JsonResponse($dataRespuesta);
            } catch (\Exception $exc) {
                if (\in_array($exc->getCode(), [404, 406])) {
                    return new Response($exc->getMessage(), $exc->getCode());
                }
                $logger->error(sprintf("[%s:%s]: %s", self::class, __FUNCTION__, $exc->getMessage()));
                return new Response("Ocurrió un error inesperado al ejecutar la operación", 500);
            }
        } else {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException("Recurso no encontrado.");
        }
    }
```

Repository:

```
public function embarazadasPorEstructuraDTable(EstructuraOrganizativa $estructura, $start = 1, $length = 10, $verTodos = false, $filtroNombre = ''): array
    {
        $tipoEstructuraId = $estructura->getTipoEstructuraOrganizativa()->getId();

        $mainQuery = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery();
        $countQuery = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery();
        $totalResultsQuery = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery();
        $mainDql = "SELECT e, tc, ub, cmf, gbt, asalud, mcpio, prov FROM App:Embarazada e JOIN e.tipoCaptacion tc JOIN e.ubicacion ub JOIN e.estructuraOrganizativa cmf JOIN cmf.parent gbt JOIN gbt.parent asalud JOIN asalud.parent mcpio JOIN mcpio.parent prov";
        $countDql = "SELECT COUNT(e.id) FROM App:Embarazada e JOIN e.estructuraOrganizativa cmf JOIN cmf.parent gbt JOIN gbt.parent asalud JOIN asalud.parent mcpio JOIN mcpio.parent prov";
        $totalResultDql = "SELECT COUNT(e.id) FROM App:Embarazada e JOIN e.estructuraOrganizativa cmf JOIN cmf.parent gbt JOIN gbt.parent asalud JOIN asalud.parent mcpio JOIN mcpio.parent prov";
        switch ($tipoEstructuraId) {
            case 2:
                $mainDql .= " WHERE (prov = :estructuraId)";
                $countDql .= " WHERE (prov = :estructuraId)";
                $totalResultDql .= " WHERE (prov = :estructuraId)";
                break;
            case 3:
                $mainDql .= " WHERE (mcpio = :estructuraId)";
                $countDql .= " WHERE (mcpio = :estructuraId)";
                $totalResultDql .= " WHERE (mcpio = :estructuraId)";
                break;
            case 4:
                $mainDql .= " WHERE (asalud = :estructuraId)";
                $countDql .= " WHERE (asalud = :estructuraId)";
                $totalResultDql .= " WHERE (asalud = :estructuraId)";
                break;
            case 5:
                $mainDql .= " WHERE (gbt = :estructuraId)";
                $countDql .= " WHERE (gbt = :estructuraId)";
                $totalResultDql .= " WHERE (gbt = :estructuraId)";
                break;
            case 6:
                $mainDql .= " WHERE (cmf = :estructuraId)";
                $countDql .= " WHERE (cmf = :estructuraId)";
                $totalResultDql .= " WHERE (cmf = :estructuraId)";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (!empty($filtroNombre)) {
            $mainDql .= " AND ((e.nombre LIKE :filtroNombre) OR (e.numeroIdentidad LIKE :filtroNombre))";
            $countDql .= " AND ((e.nombre LIKE :filtroNombre) OR (e.numeroIdentidad LIKE :filtroNombre))";
            $mainQuery->setParameter('filtroNombre', $filtroNombre . '%');
            $countQuery->setParameter('filtroNombre', $filtroNombre . '%');
        }

        if ($verTodos === false) {
            $mainDql .= " AND (e.embarazoFinalizado = FALSE) AND (e.fallecida IS NULL OR e.fallecida = FALSE)";
            $countDql .= " AND (e.embarazoFinalizado = FALSE) AND (e.fallecida IS NULL OR e.fallecida = FALSE)";
            $totalResultDql .= " AND (e.embarazoFinalizado = FALSE) AND (e.fallecida IS NULL OR e.fallecida = FALSE)";
        }

        $mainDql .= "  ORDER BY e.fechaUltimaMenstruacion ASC";

        $mainQuery->setDQL($mainDql);
        $countQuery->setDql($countDql);
        $totalResultsQuery->setDql($totalResultDql);

        $mainQuery->useQueryCache(true);
        $countQuery->useQueryCache(true);
        $totalResultsQuery->useQueryCache(true);

        $mainQuery->setParameter('estructuraId', $estructura->getId());
        $countQuery->setParameter('estructuraId', $estructura->getId());
        $totalResultsQuery->setParameter('estructuraId', $estructura->getId());

        $mainQuery->setFirstResult($start);
        $mainQuery->setMaxResults($length);

        $resultados = $mainQuery->getResult();
        $countResults = $countQuery->getSingleScalarResult();
        $totalResults = $totalResultsQuery->getSingleScalarResult();

        $resultado = ["results" => $resultados, "countResults" => $countResults, "totalResults" => $totalResults];

        return $resultado;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La inconsistencia se debe a que solo ordenas por la ultima fecha del periodo. Debes ampliar el ordenamiento a otros campos para tratar de mantener un resultado homogeneo.

Comment: Efectivamente, amplié el ORDER BY a que incluyera el campo nombre y listo, mantiene dentro de la misma página el orden de las filas.